# using facebook connect to authorize or login on your website

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

There are times when we need a registered member on our website that allows one to access a page that is only displayed if the user is logged into our website. Are normally we use the registration form to register a new user into our website. With the rapid development of the internet of course one sometimes forgets the user and password that was created on a website because of too many usernames that should be remembered. We can create an alternative to our diwebsite member registration using facebook connect. so users no longer need to remember lots of usernames and passwords simply by facebook account.

how to make it. thanks: D

Comment: Thanks for the spiel on the current state of web authentication.  However, your question essentially consists of "how do I use facebook connect to allow users to login to my website?"  That is a very broad question, out of the scope of a StackOverflow question. Additionally, you've shown no effort of doing it yourself (if you have tried, please exhibit said effort in your question).  Sorry if I'm being a bit preachy but your question is coming off as "please do this for me," and that's not the purposes of SO.

Comment: start by reading this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook latest php sdk to integrate facebook features in your site. Some days ago facebook released their new graph api system and updated their core structure. They also officially released php sdk so that you can easily call facebook latest graph api and old legacy api from server side by php.

Lot of tutorials are there for facebook connect.

I would like to suggest

[PHP SDK & Graph API base Facebook Connect Tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Everything is explained here.